# fcntl.ioctl always fails on Python 2

Tags: python, ioctl

The following always fails:

```
import fcntl
import termios

buffer = bytearray(8)
fcntl.ioctl(2, termios.TIOCGWINSZ, buffer, True)
```

Always fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testit.py", line 5, in <module>
    fcntl.ioctl(2, termios.TIOCGWINSZ, buffer, True)
TypeError: ioctl requires a file or file descriptor, an integer and optionally an integer or buffer argument
```

- The first argument trivially meets the "file descriptor" criteria.
- `termios.TIOCGWINSZ` == 21523, an integer
- the third argument is a buffer.

**Why?** It executes fine in Python 3, but alas, we use Python 2 in production.

**Edit:** This is very similar to [Python's issue #10345](http://bugs.python.org/issue10345), except unlike the filer of that bug, I *am* using a mutable buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `bytearray` is not the buffer type you're looking for.

This works:

```
import fcntl
import termios
import array

buffer = array.array('h', [0]*8)
assert fcntl.ioctl(2, termios.TIOCGWINSZ, buffer, True) == 0
print buffer  # first two bytes are set to terminal's height and width.
```

Comment: Okay… why does that work? The docs claim, "or an object supporting the read-write buffer interface" — does `bytearray` not support that? (In Python 2, only?)

Comment: [The docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.ioctl) in the example section suggest that the `array` module should be used for a mutable buffer. E.g. `bytearray` lacks the `buffer_info` method which returns the pointer that `fcntl` wants. `ctypes` also work: `buf = (ctypes.c_byte * 4)(0, 0, 0, 0)`, pass it to the call, and see what `list(buf)` shows. Probably Python3 just learned to do this trick with `bytearray` behind the scenes, though I couldn't readily find any info on that.